# pdf opening unsafe blob in new tab angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, blob, arraybuffer

I am trying to open a pdf file that i call from the server, i receive the file in the format of an arraybuffer. I tried many ways to open the pdf file in a new tab using $window.open and converting the file to other forms. Before you suggest downloading, it works but I want to open it in a new tab and it being safe to view as a popup.

The pdf opens with this url after converting it to a blob: 
"blob:http://console:8012/3c8b129d-3544-4f7e-a606-cf4b5eb6e1f3"
and my problem is that it is unsafe because it starts with a blob: and chrome marks it as unsafe.

Anybody got a clue how to fix this ?
Thanks

Comment: nfokho @user3909194

Comment: Read [AngularJS $compileProvider API Reference - aHrefSanitizationWhitelist](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider#aHrefSanitizationWhitelist).

Comment: Please provide the code used to open the pdf in a new tab and the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `$compileProvider` in config block of your angular app and add following line:

```
 $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(blob):/);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but i already have it written and still the blob is marked as unsafe

Comment: actually i was doing the same yesterday and it worked for me.

Comment: I added it to the main.js file like this               app.config(function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(blob):/);
});                                is it correct like that ?

Answer (score 1):

The default sanitization white lists for AngularJS v1.6 are[<sup>1</sup>](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blame/master/src/ng/sanitizeUri.js#L8):

```
var  aHrefSanitizationWhitelist = /^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|tel|file):/,
    imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist = /^\s*((https?|ftp|file|blob):|data:image\/)/;
```

Use the [$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/%24compileProvider#aHrefSanitizationWhitelist) to add `blob` to its white list.

```
app.config(function($compileProvider) {
    var hrefWhiteList = /^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|tel|file|blob):/;
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(hrefWhiteList);
});
```